# Visual Studio Exe App compilation path change

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just want to change the exe file Visual Studio  compilation path change

I am doing it like this now.  i created a bat file that copied file. I have added visual studio build events. I wonder if there is an easier way.
meanwhile the exe file is being copied to the network drive

[image]

Comment: It sounds like all you are looking to do is change your output path when you build a project?

Comment: @TimothyG. then all the files of the project are discarded, dll files etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a different context (Elixir/Phoenix, Rust), but the root cause was the same: cl.exe could not be found during compilation.

My setup was:

Windows 10, x64

Visual Studio Community 2017 already installed, but only for C# development
For some reason the solution with installing the Visual C++ Build Tools (as @cozzamara suggested) did not work. Stops during installation with some obscure error message. Guess it did not liked my existing Visual Studio installation.

This is how I solved it:

Start up the Visual Studio Installer
Check the Desktop development with C++ (screenshots here)
Execute following command before compiling:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat
```

From this on the command cl.exe works. Alternatively (and more conveniently for development) start the application 'Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017' or 'x64 Native Tools Command Prompt VS 2017'.

Share

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it with the checkmark and upvote so it can help the community.

Comment: I guess I asked the question wrong, or you got me wrong. When I build the project, I want the exe to be copied to another folder on a different network.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by writing code like this in the Post build field, I just ensured that the exe was copied to the field I wanted

COPY $(TargetPath) "\x.x.x.x\ortak\yakup\TestApp.exe"
pause

$(TargetPath) = It gives the location where the exe exited, along with the exe name
"C:\yakup\project\TestApp.exe" like